# How to properly chain rxjs 6 observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

Any suggestions, how this can be rewritten in more promise-chaining style?:

```
this.apiService.sendPutRequest('/api/users/activate', usrObj).pipe(
        map(() => {
            return this.apiService.sendGetRequest('/api/users/' + this.currentUserId).pipe(
                map(data => {
                    return this.setActiveUser(data).pipe(
                        map(() => {
                            return this.apiService.sendGetRequest('api/tasks/user/' + this.currentUserId).pipe(
                                map(tasks => {
                                    return this.taskService.setCurrentUserTasks(tasks);
                                })
                            );
                        })
                    );
                })
            );
        })
    );
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [switchMap](http://rxmarbles.com/#switchMap) for handling observables and [tap](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/function/index.html#static-function-tap) for side efects handling. And you need to subscribe because it's [cold observable](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339)

For error handling use [catchError](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/function/index.html#static-function-catchError) for all requests

```
this.apiService.sendPutRequest('/api/users/activate', usrObj).pipe(
    catchError(err=> this.errorHandler(err)),
    switchMap(() => this.apiService.sendGetRequest('/api/users/' + this.currentUserId)
        .pipe(catchError(err=> this.errorHandler(err)))
    ),
    tap(data => this.setActiveUser(data)),
    switchMap(() => this.apiService.sendGetRequest('api/tasks/user/' + this.currentUserId)
        .pipe(catchError(err=> this.errorHandler(err)))
    ),
    tap(tasks => this.taskService.setCurrentUserTasks(tasks))
).subscribe()
```

Comment: Why we need catchError() for each switchMap. why can't we have one?

Comment: with one catchError when crush one observable whole stream will crushed. In this solution you can get partial data when one observable crushed. For example when `this.apiService.sendGetRequest('/api/users/' + this.currentUserId)` return error stream will continue and you can get `this.apiService.sendGetRequest('api/tasks/user/' + this.currentUserId)`

Comment: If you don't need partial data use one catchError

Comment: There is no need of nested pipes with catch error. Those can be piped in the main pipeline

Answer (score 12):

use `SwitchMap` for that.

```
mainApiCall.pipe(
    switchMap(result=>secondApiCall(result)),
    switchMap(resultFromSecondApiCall=>thirdApiCall(resultFromSecond))
...
and so on
)
```

Comment: The naming choices in this code sample are descriptive and helpful for me to quickly understand chaining together.  This got me where I needed to be with chaining various api calls together quickly. Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

Use a single `pipe` for your problem. Just comma seperate different chainable operators like `map`, `switchMap`, `mergeMap`, `tap`, etc.

```js
this.apiService.sendPutRequest('/api/users/activate', usrObj).pipe(
  switchMap((results) => this.apiService.sendGetRequest('/api/users/' + this.currentUserId)),
  tap((results) => this.setActiveUser(data)),
  switchMap(() => this.apiService.sendGetRequest('api/tasks/user/' + this.currentUserId)),
  tap((results) => this.taskService.setCurrentUserTasks(tasks))
);
```

Simplified: Use `map` if you just want to transform a value without any async api calls and pass it to another operator or a subscription, `tap` if you just want to catch values in between without transforming (e.g. for logging). And `switchMap` for dispatching additional api calls.