# How do I pipe multiple dependent Observables?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, rxjs, auth-guard

In Angular 7, I am storing a JSON Web Token (JWT) locally via `@ngx-pwa/local-storage`. To get and save key-value pairs, this API is asynchronous. I then have another method which retrieves the JWT and makes a `HttpClient` call. I cannot seem to chain and get these async methods to work.

My method to get the JWT from localstorage is as follows.

```
private getHttpHeaders(): Observerable<object> {
 return this.localStorage.getItem<string>('token', {schema: {type: 'string'}}).pipe(map(token => {
  return {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Access-Token': token
   })
  };
 }));
}
```

My other method looks like the following.

```
public isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
  const url = `${this.host}/account/isloggedin`;
  return new Observable<boolean>(observer => {
    this.getHttpHeaders()
      .pipe(map(headers => {
        return this.httpClient.get<any>(url, headers)
          .pipe(map((json) => {
            observer.next(json && json.result && json.result === true);
          }));
      }));
  });
}
```

When I attempt to call `myService.isLoggedIn()` nothing happens. If I put in `console.log` messages, I can trace that `getHttpHeaders()` is called but the Observable being returned is not invoked.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly chain rxjs 6 observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52774281/how-to-properly-chain-rxjs-6-observables)

Comment: You need to [`flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) if the callback itself returns an observable. Also you shouldn't need `new Observable`, just `return this.getHttpHeaders().pipe(flatMap(headers => this.httpClient.get(url, headers)), map(json => json && json.result === true));`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That worked!