# Rxjs return an Observable from inner observable

Tags: rxjs

I have an outer observable that i use with its result in the inner observable
and that I need to return the result from the inner observable

In the following example, I need to return the result allPersons from the second observable

the result from that function is Observable  I want the it will return Observable

```
 getAllPerson(): Observable<Data1[]> {
    return this.dataService.getIds().subscribe(
    (ids) => {
       return this.dataService.getPersons().pipe(
         map((allPersons) => {
           console.log(ids);
         //filter persons according to ids
           return allPersons;
         })
     
     })
   );
 }
```

Also tried: and get
Argument of type 'Observable' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<any, any>'.

```
getAllPerson(): Observable<any> {
   return this. dataService.getIds().pipe(
     switchMap((data) => {
       this.dataService.getPersons().subscribe(
         (allPersons) => {
            console.log(ids);
        //filter persons according to ids
          return allPersons;
         })
     })
   );
 }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52774281/how-to-properly-chain-rxjs-6-observables

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be somthing like that :

```
function getAllPerson(): Observable<Data1[]> {
  return this.dataService.getIds().pipe(
    switchMap((ids) => {
      return this.dataService.getPersons().pipe(
        map((allPersons) => {
          return allPersons.filter(...);          //filter persons according to ids
        })
      );
    })
  );
}
```

And `subscribe` the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I see you're using TypeScript (nice), but there's a type error in the first two lines of your code.

```ts
getAllPerson(): Observable<Data1[]> {
    return this.dataService.getIds().subscribe( /*more code here */ );
```

The type check is going to look at this is complain. It will say something like, "Denotationally, you've declared that this function returns an `Observable` object. By inference, I can see you're returning a `Subscription` object. As far as I can tell, `Observable` objects and `subscription` objects cannot be unified. This is a type error.

It's right.

The issue is that once you subscribe to an observable, you're no longer in RxJS land. You're left with an imperative way to end an observable, but you're done dealing with observable.

Think about subscribing as your way to exist the RxJS library. So if operators like `of`, `from`, `fromEvent`, `new Subject`, `new BehaviorSubject`, ect are ways to enter the RxJS library, then `subscribe`, `lastValueFrom`, `firstValueFrom`, `behaviorSub.value`, etc are ways to exit the RxJS library.

---

So how to avoid that dreaded subscribe. This is where RxJS hiher order operators come in. They let you chain, combine, merge, etc streams

for Example:

```ts
function getAllPerson(): Observable<Data1[]> {
  return this.dataService.getIds().pipe(
    switchMap(ids => this.dataService.getPersons().pipe(
        map(allPersons => allPersons.filter(/* filter code ...*/))
    ))
  );
}
```